# Having difficulty sizing and adding image to TCategoryButtons

Tags: delphi

I am working with Delphi Alexandria VCL and I want to add elegant buttons on the LHS of my application screen. I noticed CategoryButtons which can have a subset of buttons.

I want to use buttons that collapse and Expand.
[somethins like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQheX.png)

Issue is that I cannot find out how to increase the height of the first level of buttons. The property 'Button Height' increases the height of the sub level buttons only.

Though I added a TImageList component there is no property for assigning the Imageindex to any of the buttons therefore the images do not show either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed with a elegant look and feel with combination of TButton and TCategoryButton Sets within a Panel. A panel each for the first level of buttons. Just toggling Visible True/false on Button Click and onCollapse

Answer (score 0):

Use  TCustomImageList.GetBitmap(Index: Integer; Image: TBitmap)

Example using a imagelist in a DataModule

```
  with DataModule2.ToolbarImages do
  begin
    GetBitmap(0, SBSix.Glyph);
    ...
    GetBitmap(13, SBalarm.Glyph);
  end;
```